# Defining the rank for a finitely generated abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So first some definitions. Let $G$ be an abelian group, a **basis for $G$** is a linearly independant subset that generates $G$. We say that $G$ is **finitely generated** if a basis for $G$ is finite.

Now there's an important theorem

> *Theorem:* An abelian group is free abelian if and only if it has a basis.

So  if $G$ is finitely generated then $G$ is free abelian. Now if $H$ is a free abelian group with a finite basis we define the **rank of $H$** to be the number of elements in any finite basis for $H$.

So from all the above definitions, it seems that the notion of rank is defined for any abelian group that is finitely generated. However in my textbook *Introduction to Topological Manifolds by John Lee* the following is stated:

> "we need to extend the notion of rank to finitely generated abelian groups that are not necessarily free abelian"

But by the theorem above, I don't see how any finitely generated abelian group cannot be free abelian. An abelian group $K$ that is finitely generated has a finite basis and so by the above theorem is free abelian.

What does the author mean in this case?

---

My apologies if by mistake I have misquoted/misunderstood any content from the above mentioned book (which I consider to be a really great book!)

**EDIT:** I incorrectly assumed that $G$ is finitely generated implies that a basis for $G$ is finite.

Comment: The definition appears to be incomplete.  For the group, $G$,  of order $2$, if $g$ is the non-trivial element, isn't $\{g\}$ a "linearly independent subset that generates $G$"?  Similarly, the claim "If $G$ is finitely generated then it is free abelian" is obviously false without more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We say that G is finitely generated if a basis for G is finite.

This isn't the usual definition of finitely generated.  Usually, $G$ is said to be finitely generated if there exist $e_1, ... , e_n \in G$ such that every element of $G$ can be expressed as

$$g = c_1e_1 + \cdots + c_ne_n$$

for some $c_i \in \mathbb Z$.  This doesn't mean that $\{e_1, ... , e_n\}$ or any subset of it has to be a basis.  There exist finitely generately abelian groups which do not have any basis.

Example: $G = \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is finitely generated, by $e_1 = (1,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$.    But no subset of $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is a basis for $G$.

Comment: I assumed that $G$ is finitely generated implies that a basis for $G$ is finite, my apologies, thanks for this answer!

Comment: And for example $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is not a basis for $G$ because it isn't linearly independant since $$3(1, 0) + 3(0, 1) = (0, 0) = 0_{\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} }$$

Comment: Right $ \space$